# How can I use Python's pexpect module to capture a specific string in Linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux

I am currently working on simple python script to manage the linux terminal. I'm now trying to control the Linux command line using script writen before. The problem that occured is when trying to capture the following string: "przemektw@DESKTOP-ULCU8V7:~$" which occurs when the instruction is over.

The code uses pexepct module to check if the string already occured in the Linux terminal

[image: linux terminal]

[image: code]

I Already tried to change the format of the command and added timeout for waiting. Does anyone maybe  know how to format/change the input of the pexpect command?